# Javascript: for, switch and Math.rand in one and not working right

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, switch-statement

I'm currently working on an idle game and have encountered a problem.

I'm trying to create a function that will lessen the value of 1 of 6 variables (each represents a type of worker) a number of times. However, if one of these 6 variables is at 0, I need it to pick one of the other 5, and I can't get that to work.

With fiddling around, I have gotten this:

```
function killWorker(amount){
    var job;
    for (var i=0;i<amount;i++){ 
        job = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
        switch (job){
            case 1:
                if(unass_workers>0){
                    unass_workers -= 1;
                }else{
                    i-=1;
                }
            case 2:
                if(farm_workers>0){
                    farm_workers -= 1;
                }else{
                    i-=1;
                }
            break;
            case 3:
                if(tree_workers>0){
                    tree_workers -= 1;
                }else{
                    i-=1;
                }
            break;
            case 4:
                if(metMine_workers>0){
                    metMine_workers -= 1;
                }else{
                    i-=1;
                }
            break;
            case 5:
                if(golMine_workers>0){
                    golMine_workers -= 1;
                }else{
                    i-=1;
                }
            break;
            case 6:
                if(paper_workers>0){
                    paper_workers -= 1;
                }else{
                    i-=1;
                }
            break;
            default:
                console.log("error: killWorker() didn't work properly");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This worked when I did low amounts, but when I increased the amount higher the whole thing crashed. I'd be quite happy to drastically change the function if it would work better, and I am using jquery too if that could help get an easier or more effective solution.

Comment: I would work on finding a way to not allow your random number to reference a worker that is already 0. And a way to remove that switch statement (such as putting your workers in an object and looping over it's keys.)

Comment: Your function can potentially loop infinitely once a category runs out of workers and will surely loop infinitely once all categories run out of workers. I would assume that is what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said, what probably happens is that amount is larger than the sum of X_workers, resulting in an infinite loop.

A fix that keeps your logic correct would be to check that enough workers can be killed:

```
function killWorker(amount){
    if (amount < unass_workers + farm_workers + ...) return "Genocide";
    var job;
    for (var i=0;i<amount;i++){ 
    ...
}
```

A better way to organize your data structures could be:

```
var workerNames = [ 'unass', 'farm', 'tree', 'metMine', 'golMine', 'paper' ];
var workers = {
  unass : 23,
  farm : 45,
  tree : 6,
  metMine : 99,
  golMine : 3,
  paper:  43
}

function getRandomLiveJobName() {
  var jobs = workerNames.filter(function(name) {
    return workers[name] > 0;
  });
  return jobs[Math.floor(Math.random()*jobs.length)];
}

function killWorkers(amount) {
  for (;amount--;) {
    var job = getRandomLiveJobName();
    if (!job) return "Genocide";
    workers[job]--;
  }
}

killWorkers(150);
console.log(workers); // { farm: 0, golMine: 0, metMine: 64, paper: 5, tree: 0, unass: 0 }
```

Of course it could be optimized by not creating a new array each time you need a random live job by updating a single array inside killWorkers, but i think it's easier to read now.

Comment: Hey, so, I have tried to implement your workerNames array solution, and seem to be having problems. I've started with trying to implement it in other parts of the code first that I know were working, but is reading as NaN now.

When the page loads the following function is run. I put console logs in and found something very odd

   function initialize(){
 console.log(workers);
 show("gameMain");
 reset();
 console.log(workers);
 ...
    }

the first console.log reads correctly, but the second one reads as 0. the workers var isn't touched between then...I have no idea what's going on...

Comment: You're obviously doing something with the workers variable in between. Just pay more attention to the code you wrote.